# Unknown collections in SageMaker Debugger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-debugger

In the code I have asked for 4 collections as you see below:
[image]

But when I see the JSON file in S3, generated by debugger I have more collections like this:

Why more than what I have asked is generated? Is that for future if I change my mind and I need more collections?

[image]